# WPF TextBox scroll to end only works once

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, scroll

I have 2 TextBoxs' which contain paths to filenames. The paths are long so I want the text to display the end of the full path string so the user can see the filename and the last part of the path.

The text boxes are called

```
TxInPanel.PcmFilename
TxOutPanel.PcmFilename
```

I set the first text box to display the end of the text as follows:

```
    // Set textbox and filename
    tb = TxInPanel.PcmFilename;
    tb.Text = txInDefaultPcm.ToString();

    // Display end of filename in textbox
    tb.Focus();
    tb.CaretIndex = tb.Text.Length;
    var rect = tb.GetRectFromCharacterIndex(tb.CaretIndex);
    tb.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(rect.Right);
```

This works great!

What doesn't work, at all is when i try it again with the next text box:

```
    // Set textbox and filename
    tb = TxOutPanel.PcmFilename;
    tb.Text = txOutDefaultPcm.ToString();

    // Display end of filename in textbox
    tb.Focus();            
    tb.CaretIndex = tb.Text.Length;
    rect = tb.GetRectFromCharacterIndex(tb.CaretIndex);
    tb.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(rect.Right);
```

Which is very strange. If i swap the order above, it always works for the first text box and never the last one.

Other things I have tried, in various combinations are:

```
    tb.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(Math.Max(rect.Right, tb.HorizontalOffset));
    tb.ScrollToEnd();
```

All without success.

I should also say that the TextBox I am using comes from a UserControl I made.

```
<TextBox   Name="PcmFilename" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Height="25" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Left" />
```

When running the app, i see that the "working" textbox has a carat cursor at the end of the string, but its not blinking, its a solid vertical line, which isnt right. This makes me think the problem lies in getting Focus on the 2nd TextBox.

Does anyone have a fool proof way of displaying the last part of a sting in a textbox?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to change the `FlowDirection` to `RightToLeft` so that any text is treated with the right as the start of the text and is displayed starting at the right hand edge of the textbox.